# ifstream is only reading data 3 times

Tags: while-loop, ifstream, eof

I have a code where I need to count number of people in each gender, sum of the gpa, and average of the gpa. Despite the code being nearly identical between the male & female count it's not reading any information from the file on the second loop.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

void openFiles(ifstream& read, ofstream& write)
{
    read.open("StudentsPreformanceData.txt");

    if (read.is_open())
        cout << "File Opened" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Error try again";

    write.open("Results.txt");
    write << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
}
void initialize(int& countFemale, int& countMale, double& sumFemale, double& sumMale)
{
    countFemale = 0;
    countMale = 0;
    sumFemale = 0.00;
    sumMale = 0.00;
}
void sumGrades(ifstream& read, double& sum, char gender)
{
    char student;
    double grade;
    while (!read.eof())
    {
        read >> student;
        read >> grade;
        if (student == gender)
            sum = sum + grade;

        //cout << student << " " << grade << " " << sum << endl;
    }
    read.close();
}
double averageGrades(ifstream& read, double sum, int& count, char gender)
{
    char student;
    double grade;
    while (!read.eof())
    {
        read >> student;
        read >> grade;
        if (student == gender)
        {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        cout << student << " " << count << " " << sum << endl;
    }
    return sum / count;
    read.close();
}
void printResults()
{

}

int main()
{
    ifstream read;
    ofstream write;
    openFiles(read, write);

    int countFemale, countMale;
    double sumFemale, sumMale;
    initialize(countFemale, countMale, sumFemale, sumMale);

    cout << countFemale << sumFemale << countMale << sumMale << endl;

    sumGrades(read, sumFemale, 'f');
    cout << countFemale << " " << sumFemale << " " << countMale << " " << sumMale << endl;

    openFiles(read, write);

    sumGrades(read, sumMale, 'm');
    cout << countFemale << " " << sumFemale << " " << countMale << " " << sumMale << endl;

    openFiles(read, write);

    averageGrades(read, sumMale, countMale, 'm');
    cout << countFemale << " " << sumFemale << " " << countMale << " " << sumMale << endl;

    openFiles(read, write);

    averageGrades(read, sumFemale, countFemale, 'f');
    cout << countFemale << " " << sumFemale << " " << countMale << " " << sumMale << endl;
}
```

[The attached image is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71U0I.png)

I'm confused because I tried swapping male and females places and again which ever is second didn't count. the code prints out file opened so I know its being opened, i just don't no why it won't run through the list for a 4th time at that point in the code.

Comment: Oof, that code ... Do you have someone who can give you advise on how to write better code? A tutor, teacher, mentor, ideally a professional programmer with some years of experience in C++?

Comment: I wish... its for a class an a lot of it is because of the loop holes I have to jump through for an assignment. like the initialize and open file functions are not of my own volition.

Comment: This code violates SRP (single responsibility principle), PLA (principle of least astonishment), DRY (don't repeat yourself). It looks a bit like C++ but most of the implementation is C-style. Reading the file over and over instead of reading it once into a data structure and processing the data structure multiple times, ... You could probably rework this code 10 times - and you should go through that pain. Just to see the difference between the first version and  the 10th version. That way you'll learn about the choices you can make, how those choices look and feel.

Comment: I do this with my students. But that takes time - a lot of time. I'd say I could easily spend 4x 1 hour on this, discussing with you and introducing you to new concepts.  After each such hour, you'd implement and do some research for 4+ hours yourself. We can't teach you that on Stack Overflow, IMHO.